# How to check or set room availability in Django

Tags: django, django-models, orm

I am building a hotel booking system. I am quite new to Django and i am kindly asking for directions on how to carry out setting or checking for room availability implementation. I have designed my room model in a way that a specific room type can have several quantities. I want to implement the system in such a way that before a user makes a booking the room should have enough quantity and also be available on that specific date duration specified by the user. The following is code for room and booking model

**Room Model**

```
class Room(models.Model):
    """Creates room details"""

    ROOM_CHOICES = (
        ('Single', "Single"),
        ('Double', "Double"),
        ('Family', "Family"),
        ('Suit', "Suit"),
    )

    hotel = models.ForeignKey(
        Hotels, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True,)
    room_Type = models.CharField(
        max_length=20,
        choices=ROOM_CHOICES,
        default='Please Select',
    )
    room_photo = models.ImageField(
        default='default.jpg', upload_to='room_photos')
    room_Name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    room_details = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    room_Capacity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    room_Price = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    total_Rooms = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)#room quantity
```

**Booking (Cart) Model**

```
class CartItems(models.Model):
    cart = models.ForeignKey(
        'Cart', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    rooms = models.ForeignKey(
        Room, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
    line_total = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=1000, decimal_places=2, default=0.00)
    CheckIn = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    CheckOut = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    stay_duration = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
```

In summary before the user submits or confirms a booking the room quantity and checkin and checkout duration should be available. How do i do this implementation. Kindly assist. Thanks very much in advance

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I won't provide full code for you. But you need to implement a function in the view. When a user submits the form, you send a request to this view. Where the check of the room's availability is performed and based on that render success or failed page.

You can do it dynamically (without page reload), but AJAX is needed for that. Still, javascript will send the request to the view.